# Redirect to route results 'HTTP 500 Error' in laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I am developing a `Laravel` site. After a user registers and logs in, there are some jobs done for him and the the user should be redirected to a rout. Unfortunately, none of the redirections below produce a working page:
`1: return Redirect::route('startChoose');
2: return redirect()->route('startChoose');`

Below is the `route` that I've put in the `web.php` file:
`Route::get('/startChoose', 'StartChooseController@index');`

And this is the StartChooseController:
[image]

Would you please help me figure out what the problem can be? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [name your route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes) to make `route()` helper build correct URL:

```
Route::get('/startChoose', 'StartChooseController@index')->name('startChoose');
```

Or:

```
Route::get('/startChoose', ['as' => 'startChoose', 'uses' => 'StartChooseController@index']);
```

If you don't want to name your route, use this syntax instead:

```
return redirect('startChoose');
```